# I'm trying to place my form at the center of the page in css. I have tried different alignments but i can't

Tags: html, css, alignment

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #d90429;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.form{
    display:inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
    <!-- <h2 class="subHeading">EXPLORE</h2> -->
    <h1 class="heading">REGISTER</h1>
    <form action="" class=form>
        <input type="text" id=email>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here are my code. Help me to find out the solution

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMCHf.png)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded to my question. My problem is solved by adding position property to relative in formContainer class.

.formContainer{
 position:relative;
 display:flexbox;
 justify-content:center;
 }

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try setting margin-left to auto and margin-right to auto and remove the current css.

Alternatively you could use display:flex, flex-direction:row, justify-content:center

Comment: I already tried this . When i try this method the form is placed in the top-left corner of my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from inline-block to block also justify content does not work outside of a flex element. Change you form class with this

```
body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: #d90429;
  margin:0%;
  padding:0%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.form{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
     max-width:50rem;
}
```

Add a max width of 50 or just to see it

Comment: Sorry. I have tried what you have suggested. It does'nt work

Comment:  you need to specify the width and height of its parent in other words you need to add `width:100vw;` and `height:100vh;` at your body styles

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body{
  background-color: #d90429;
  margin:0%;
  padding:0%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.form{
  background: blue;
  display:block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form label {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <!-- <h2 class="subHeading">EXPLORE</h2> -->
    <h1 class="heading">REGISTER</h1>
    <form action="" class=form>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id=email>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id=password>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This one too doesn't works. The form is placed above the register heading. I think some other things like navbar and footer affecting its position since that included in my code.

Comment: This is how we can help you seeing your posted code..